# mysql construct "insert into ... select ... on duplicate key update" in MSSQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, insert-update

In mysql I use this simple yet powerful construction to insert-or-update the whole table at once:

```
INSERT INTO mytable
            SELECT * FROM source_table ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
            val1 = VALUES(val1),
            val2 = VALUES(val2),
            val3 = VALUES(val3),
            val4 = VALUES(val4)
```

I know how to deal with a single insert-update on MS SQL, But how to do this "bulk update" on MS SQL 2014?

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent in MS SQL Server is MERGE  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Comment: it looks like I need to manually write all column names in insert section instead of * ?